# Solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-4x}{x-y}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-4x}{x-y}$.

I used the substitution $y(x)=v(x)x$ and got $v+xv'=\frac{v-4}{1-v}$. But I am not sure what do I do after this? What method do I need?

Comment: you will end up with a separable integral - $$\int g(v)dv = \int \frac{1}{x}dx + C$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify down to

$$v+xv'=\frac{v-4}{1-v}$$ $$\implies xv'=\frac{v-4}{1-v} - v$$ $$\implies v'=\frac{\frac{v-4}{1-v} - v}{x}$$ $$\implies \frac{1}{\frac{v-4}{1-v} - v}v'=\frac 1x $$ $$\implies \frac{1-v}{(v-2)(v+2)}v' = \frac{1}{x}$$

which is a separable equation. You can therefore integrate and solve

$$\int\frac{1-v}{(v-2)(v+2)}\,dv = \int \frac{1}{x}\,dx$$

and then re-substitute $y=vx$ to solve for $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a dif. Eq. Of separate variables and all the consept is to write $v'$ as the fraction $\frac{dv}{dx}$ then v goes to the other side, multiply the equation with the differential $dx$ and then take the integrals such that you have the form $\int f(v) dv = \int g(x) dx +c$ and try to compute them.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract $v$ from. both sides and separate variables.

Integrate both sides and solve for $v$ if possible.

Back substitution will give you a solution in terms of $x$ and $y$